# How to get x value from mschart based on clicked mouse position

Tags: c, mschart

Hello i have Mschart on a winform y axis is value 1,2 ... and x axis is date/time.I need to get the  time of the clicked point till i tried several version but i out of bussines

```
void detailChart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string ceva = detailChart.Series[1].Points[e.X].GetValueByName("X").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been battling with this with Line Charts for a few hours and came up with a solution using Cursor position and use the MouseUp or MouseDown event to get the date time object from the X axis.

You can change the Cursor colour if you need to hide it, and please refer to Cursors in the Chart Samples provided with MSCharts.

```
private void chartLine_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(chartLine.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position);
}
```

Comment: Please make sure CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true for this to work.